# Error from creating profile update in django

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am trying to create a profile update in django application and I got the following error in the browser

```
local variable 'form' referenced before assignment
```

any help would be appreciated. I am confused right now. Below is my views.py. Thanks

**View.py**

```
def update_profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UpdateProfile(request.POST or None, instance=request.user)
        profile_form = ProfileEditForm(data = request.POST or None,instance=request.user,files=request.FILES)

        if form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            profile_form.save()
            return redirect('profiles')
    else:
        form = UpdateProfile(instance=request.user)
        profile_form = ProfileEditForm(instance=request.user)
    context = {
        "form": form,
        "profile_form": profile_form,
    }
    template = 'edit.html'
    return render(request, template, context)
```

**Error Trace**

```
Traceback:

File "/Users/Olar/Desktop/arbithub/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  41.             response = get_response(request)

File "/Users/Olar/Desktop/arbithub/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/Users/Olar/Desktop/arbithub/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/Users/Olar/Desktop/arbithub/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  23.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/Olar/Desktop/arbithub/src/profiles/views.py" in update_profile
  49.         if form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():

Exception Type: UnboundLocalError at /profile/edit/
Exception Value: local variable 'form' referenced before assignment
```

**form.py**

```
class UpdateProfile(forms.ModelForm):
    username = forms.CharField(required=True)
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    first_name = forms.CharField(required=False)
    last_name = forms.CharField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'username', 'email']

class ProfileEditForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('date_of_birth', 'photo')
```

additional codes would be provided based on request.

Comment: please, add full error trace

Comment: @Navid2zp I need it there.

Comment: @BearBrown added the error trace

Comment: Is this the same indentation as for your running code? Note in particular the inner `if`.

Comment: yes same indentation

Comment: real magic for me, if you can, add your form definition, please

Comment: added @BearBrown

Comment: i can't find solution, but if i have the same error, i try the code `form = UpdateProfile(request.POST)` and after `form.is_valid()` set form instance by `form.instance=request.user`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def update_profile(request):
    form = UpdateProfile()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UpdateProfile(data = request.POST or None, instance=request.user)
        profile_form = ProfileEditForm(data = request.POST or None,instance=request.user,files=request.FILES)

        if form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            profile_form.save()
            return redirect('profiles')
    else:
        form = UpdateProfile(instance=request.user)
        profile_form = ProfileEditForm(instance=request.user)
    context = {
        "form": form,
        "profile_form": profile_form,
    }
    template = 'edit.html'
    return render(request, template, context)
```

Comment: error  ` 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'is_valid' `

Comment: it works now but the  profile_form does not display on the browser

Comment: try to add a `print(profile_form)` before `return` statement to check in terminal if your variable is being assigned.

Comment: @King Something is probably wrong with your indentation, even if it doesn't look like it. Getting a `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'is_valid'` error indicates that the first two `if`s are not nested as they should. As far as I can see, your original code should run without the error about a variable being referenced before assignment, because `form` was being created on both paths (`if` and `else`).